# Hibernate 4 TransactionManagerLookup in Jetty

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I've been trying to get Hibernate 4 up and running in Jetty, however, the application I'm using specifies a deprecated TransactionManagerLookup (Bitronix).

I was wondering if there's a good alternative to use, as there is not one listed specifically for Jetty in the documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-transactionstrategy). Alternatively, can Bitronix be used for this in a way which is not deprecated.

Versions:

- Jetty 6.1.18
- Hibernate 4.0.0.Final
- Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate 4 got its JTA code and configuration heavily reworked since 3.x. The Bitronix TM is not deprecated but the TransactionManagerLookup implementations are.

Have a look there to figure out what needs to be changed to be able to use BTM with Hibernate 4: http://old.nabble.com/Bitronix-Lookup-in-HIbernate-4-td33071521.html

Comment: Broken link, can it be found anywhere else?